# Problem creating loop for repeat search option, advice for underlining search query occurrences

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, search

I'm running into a problem writing a search method that iterates through an array list of lines of text and repeats the search.

In addition, I'm also running into a wall trying to create a loop that underscores the occurrences of the search query in the line. Like so:

```
Enter Search Pattern: he
Line number 1
Her old collecting she considered discovered. 
                    ^
Line number 2
So at parties he warrant oh staying. Square new horses and put better end. 
              ^
Line number 8
Pursuit he he garrets greater towards amiable so placing. 
        ^  ^
Line number 9
Nothing off how norland delight. Abode shy shade she hours forth its use.
                                                  ^
```

I've been able to code the method to search a line(it returns the text above as expected), but I'm hitting the wall trying to get the search to repeat, that is, prompt the user for additional search queries to perform another search.

Also, any clue how to do the highlighting with the ^ like above? I haven't been able to find anything to help me.

Here is my code for the method. I've included the main, and search method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
  if(args.length == 0){
    System.out.println("Error, usage: java ClassName inputfile");
    System.exit(1);
  }
  File randomText = new File(args[0]);
    if(randomText.exists() && randomText.isFile()){
      processFile(randomText);
    } else{
        System.err.println("ERROR: file does not exist");
        System.exit(1);
      }
//there are more methods to this program, like to call the search method, I just included the code in question.
 }

public static void search(ArrayList<String> lineList){
  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Search Pattern: ");
  String searchQuery = userInput.nextLine();
  int i=0;
  for (String line : lineList){
    i++;
    if(line.contains(searchQuery)){
      System.out.println("Line number " + i);
      System.out.println(line);
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it will always line up perfectly, but this should work. I'm trying to build a new highlight string, which has a space for every character in `line` apart from the start of the matching `searchQuery` where the character is `^`.

You can find the index of your matching `searchQuery` with [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).

```java
    public static String padString(int start, int index){
       String pad = new String();
       for(int i=start; i<index; i++){
          pad = pad + " ";
       }
       return pad;
    }
    
    public static String getHighlight(String line, String searchQuery){
       String highlight = new String();
       int index = line.indexOf(searchQuery);   
    
       while(index >= 0){
          highlight = highlight + padString(highlight.length(), index) + "^";
          index = line.indexOf(searchQuery, index+1);
       }
       
       return highlight;
    }
    
    public static void search(ArrayList<String> lineList){
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter Search Pattern: ");
      String searchQuery = userInput.nextLine();
      int i=0;
      for (String line : lineList){
        i++;
        if(line.contains(searchQuery)){
          System.out.println("Line number " + i);
          System.out.println(line);
          System.out.println(getHighlight(line, searchQuery));
          }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this sort of thing working properly is the fact that the font being used to display the file line Strings and the the possible ***locator*** strings (...^...) is of a Monospaced type font. All characters within a Monospaced font are of the same fixed size and therefore the letters and characters of that font each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. Examples of such fonts are:

```
Andalé Mono       Cascadia Code       Consolas            Courier
Cutive Mono       DejaVu Sans Mono    Droid Sans Mono     Everson Mono
Fira Mono         Fixed               Fixedsys            Go Mono
HyperFont         IBM Plex Mono       Inconsolata         Iosevka
Letter Gothic     Liberation Mono     Lucida Console      Menlo
Monaco            Monofur             Monospace (Unicode) Nimbus Mono L
Noto Mono         OCR-A               OCR-B               Overpass Mono 
Oxygen Mono       PragmataPro         Prestige Elite      ProFont 
PT Mono           Roboto Mono         Source Code Pro     Terminus
Tex Gyre Cursor   UM Typewriter
```

There are more. Do a search to for Monospaced Typefaces for a complete list. The bottom line is, if a monospaced font is used then you can be assured that the *locator* character (**^**) will always be at the exact start location where your desired search string(s) are found.

In order to continuously do searches, you will need to wrap your call to the `search()` method in a loop like a `while` loop for example. You should then also modify the `search()` method to return a String, for example, what was entered into the prompt but only if it is the letter '**q**' (for quit) otherwise return nothing (null string ("")). With this is play you can do something like this:

```
// Continuously do one search after another until
// q is supplied as a search query
while (true) {
    if (search(list, true).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        break;   // Break out of the 'while' loop
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("<< DONE >>");
```

The **search()** method code below allows for letter case to be ignored if required. If the ArrayList contains:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Her old collecting she considered discovered. ");
list.add("So at parties he warrant oh staying. Square new horses and put better end.");
list.add("Pursuit he he garrets greater towards amiable so placing.");
```

then just call `search(list, true);`. If `he` was supplied at the search criteria prompt then the output result will be:

```
Enter Search Pattern: --> he
Line number 1
Her old collecting she considered discovered. 
^                   ^                         
Line number 2
So at parties he warrant oh staying. Square new horses and put better end.
              ^                                                           
Line number 3
Pursuit he he garrets greater towards amiable so placing.
        ^  ^
```

Here is the new **search()** method:

```
public static String search(ArrayList<String> lineList, boolean ignoreLetterCase) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Search Pattern (q to quit): --> ");
    String searchQuery = userInput.nextLine();
    if (searchQuery.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        return "q";
    }
    int lineCounter = 0;
    for (String line : lineList) {
        lineCounter++;
        // Generate the 'location' string. Returns null 
        // if the search item was not found!
        String found = getFoundDisplayLine(line, searchQuery, ignoreLetterCase);
        if (found != null) {
            System.out.println("Line number " + lineCounter);
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(found);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

And here is the **getFoundDisplayLine()** method which generates the 'location' string:

```
public static String getFoundDisplayLine(String inputString, String queryString, boolean... ignoreLetterCase) {
    if (inputString == null || inputString.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    String wrkStrg = inputString;
    String findStrg = queryString;

    boolean ignoreCase = false;
    if (ignoreLetterCase.length > 0) {
        ignoreCase = ignoreLetterCase[0];
    }
    if (ignoreCase) {
        wrkStrg = wrkStrg.toLowerCase();
        findStrg = queryString.toLowerCase();
    }

    String indexes = "";

    List<Integer> idx = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = wrkStrg.indexOf(findStrg);
    while (index >= 0) {
        idx.add(index);
        indexes += (indexes.isEmpty()) ? String.valueOf(index) : ", " + String.valueOf(index);
        index = wrkStrg.indexOf(findStrg, index + findStrg.length());
    }
    if (idx.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        if (idx.contains(i)) {
            sb.append("^");
        }
        else {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```